# How to call tasks from a separate module in Verilog?

Tags: task, verilog, iverilog

I'm new to Verilog and would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this. 
 I have a task written in a separate file - "task.v" :

```
module task_create();

task assign_inp;
    reg a,b,c,d;
    //details
endtask

endmodule
```

I have a module that is calling this task:

```
module tb();
    `include "task.v"
    assign_inp(a,b,c,d);
endmodule
```

When I execute this, I get this error:

> Module definition task_create cannot nest into module tb

When I remove the module and endmodule in task.v, I get this error:

> Task must be contained inside a module

Where am I going wrong? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your task is in a module and so can only be seen in the module. You can remove the module wrapper and just declare the task in a separate file.

```
task assign_inp;
    reg a,b,c,d;
    //details
endtask
```

You can include the task, and you should be able to see the task.

Removing the modules works for me.

You may need to declare the Verilog file as a header file for the task

Comment: I tried doing what you said. I removed the module wrapper used 
` `include "task.v"` 
`module tb();`
`assign_inp(a,b,c,d);`
`endmodule`
But am still getting the error _task declarations must be contained inside a module_

Comment: put the include statement inside the module declaration.

Comment: I'm really sorry, these questions are probably silly, but I'm still getting the same error!

Comment: What simulator are you using?

Comment: I'm using iverilog

Comment: You might be including the task.v as a verilog source when you compile. If you are, don't include it in the list of sources that you compile, but include the directory so the compiler knows where the include file is located using the -I option

Comment: When I try that, I get unknown module type: assign_inp, these modules were missing - assign_inp

Comment: Oh, this is because you are instantiating the task like a module. Tasks are called with a statement such as inside an initial or an always block.